# How to check if punctuation exists in a given amount of characters and if it does cut the text there - PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to check if there is a fullstop or question mark (i.e two needles) in the first 100 characters of an excerpt. If there is one then the excerpt would be cut off at the full stop, else it would be cut off at 100 characters.

Now I have the following which checks the position of the the needle: if it is under 100 characters then the excerpt is cut there, else the excerpt is cut at 100 characters with "...". The issue I have is that I wish to check for multiple needles, I have tried various methods such as looping and preg_match, but can get neither to work. Very new to php, so any pointers are much appreciated.

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    the_excerpt();
    $excerpt = ob_get_clean();
    $excerpt = preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $excerpt);;
    ?>
    <?php 

    $needle = '.';
    $position = stripos($excerpt, $needle);

    if($position < 100) {
        $offset = $position + 0;
        $position2 = stripos ($excerpt, $needle, $offset);
        $first_two = substr ($excerpt, 0, $position2);
        echo $first_two . '.';
    }

    else {
        $cut = substr( $excerpt, 0, 100 );

        $excerpt = substr( $cut, 0, strrpos( $cut, ' ' ) ) . '...';

        echo $excerpt;
    }        
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this. It needs lesser loops, and makes it possible to easily add needles. Cut the string at 100 characters right away. It is not going to be longer, there is no need to search the whole string.

```
<?php 
    ob_start();
    the_excerpt();
    $excerpt = ob_get_clean();  

    $maxLength = 100;
    $excerpt   = substr(preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $excerpt), 0, $maxLength);

    $needles    = ['.','?'];
    $offset     = min($maxLength, strlen($excerpt));
    $lnf        = $offset; // to store last needle found

    for ($index = 0; $index < $offset; $index++) {
      if (in_array($excerpt[$index], $needles)) {
         $lnf = $index + 1;
      }
    } 

    $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $lnf);

    ?>
```

Comment: very easily understood solution, thanks. Could this also be applied if I wish to cut the excerpt after the second needle?

Comment: Second needle, or second occurance of either of the needles? Right now it uses the one that is closest to the end of the excerpt.

Comment: Second occurance, but I guess it is actually best to cut the string instead of just taking the second occurance, otherwise the excerpts will vary greatly in length. Much better than I actually originally planned.

Comment: You could add a minimum value. In case a text starts with a very short sentence, display the first 100 characters.

Comment: I cant seem to find any documentation on using "in", in an if statement? When inserting the code I get a syntax error 'unexpected in'

Comment: something is still not right: 'invalid argument supplied for FOREACH()'

Comment: I need more coffee. Code adjusted.

Comment: impressive, now I just need to learn what you did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with a regex.

- Match all the needles <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>!</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd>. Of course you can add more ore remove.
- PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag gives the position where it was found
- iterate thru the results backwards
- take that one with <= 100 and cut from there.

```php
$lorem = 'Shields up, sub-light advice! The pathway dies mind like a solid klingon. The space is tightly biological. C-beams walk on beauty at earth!';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/\.|\!|\?|,|;/', $lorem, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
for($i = count($matches[0])-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo $matches[0][$i][1], PHP_EOL;
    if($matches[0][$i][1] <= 100) {
        echo "cutting at ", $matches[0][$i][1], PHP_EOL;
        $excerpt = substr($lorem, 0, $matches[0][$i][1] + 1) . ' ...';
        break;
    }
}
echo $excerpt, PHP_EOL;
```

Outputting

> 138
>   105
>   72
>   cutting at 72

The final result then is

> Shields up, sub-light advice! The pathway dies mind like a solid klingon. ...

Of course you can remove the echoes, they are just for helping to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You want to have the last occurrence of `needle` or all occurrences?

```
// dont use the buffering, there is also a get_the_excerpt function
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$needle = '.';

// use strrpos to get the last occurrence or strpos to get the first
$needle_pos = strrpos(substr($excerpt,0,100), $needle);
if($needle_pos !== false) {
   // we have a needle, so lets change the excerpt
   $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $needle_pos);
}

echo substr($excerpt, 0, 100) . '..'; // when its already cut it is less then 100 chars
```

Or even better, you could be looking into using filters. A filter is something from Wordpress. Everywhere in the Wordpress code there are function calls to `apply_filters([somename], $somevariable)`. It will execute all functions connected to that `[somename]` tag by providing the `$somevariable` and storing the return value there. You can add your own filters by using `add_filter([somename], [some callback])`. E.g.:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', cutoffExcerpt);

function cutoffExcerpt($excerpt) {
    $needle = '.';

    // use strrpos to get the last occurrence or strpos to get the first
    $needle_pos = strrpos(substr($excerpt,0,100), $needle);
    if($needle_pos !== false) {
       // we have a needle, so lets change the excerpt
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $needle_pos);
    }

    return substr($excerpt, 0, 100) . '..'; // when its already cut it is less then 100 chars
}
```

You should add this to your functions.php file in your theme (or create that file if you don't have it yet). Now when you use `the_excerpt()` in your template it will be cut off at the needle without any extra hassle.

Answer (score 0):

use PHP [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to brake needles

```
$excerpt  = "The trees, therefore, must be such old and primitive techniques that they thought nothing of them, deeming them so inconsequential that even savages like us would know of them and not be suspicious. At that, they probably didn't have too much time after they detected us orbiting and intending to land. And if that were true, there could be only one place where their civilization was hidden.";
$needles=['.','?',','];
$str=[$excerpt];
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($needles);$i++) {
    if($i!=0){
        $str[0] .= $needles[$i-1];
    }
    $str=explode($needles[$i],$str[0]);
}

if(strlen($str[0])<100){
    $excerpt=$str[0];
}
else{
    $excerpt=substr($excerpt,0,100);
    $excerpt .= "...";
}
echo $excerpt;
```